# Pg::st execute failed: ERROR: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

Tags: postgresql

When I run the script from perl, it is throwing the below error:

> SELECT  create_bDBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement at /opt/ETL/perlLib/dlLib.pl line 77.
>   dcprodidx();

It was working fine in another environment with the same code. Only difference was the perl version is 5.008005 and on the new server where it is failing is 5.010001.

```
sub executeSQL
{
my $dbHandle = shift;
my $sql = shift;


$query = $dbHandle->prepare( ${sql} )or throw Error::Simple "[ERROR] (database): Cannot prepare SQL statement: ${sql}.  $DBI::errstr\n";

$result = $query->execute or throw Error::Simple "[ERROR] (database): Data load error - Cannot execute SQL statement: ${sql}. $DBI::errstr\n" ;
$query->finish();

# return 1; ## return gracefully. Ungracefully will be "return 0"
return $result;
}
```

SQL query that is failing:

```
SELECT drop_bdcprodidx();

/* Update existing data */
update bdc_products
set
description=b.description,
page_type=b.page_type,
keyf_category_home=b.keyf_category_home,
giftwrappable=b.giftwrappable,
action_publish=b.action_publish,
action_viewable=b.action_viewable,
keyf_syndicate=b.keyf_syndicate,
sss_base_fee_exempt_flag=b.sss_base_fee_exempt_flag,
sss_surcharge_fee=b.sss_surcharge_fee,
dvm_d=b.dvm_d,
dvm_v=b.dvm_v,
division=b.division,
keyf_images_primary=b.keyf_images_primary,
option4_flag=b.option4_flag,
keyf_producttype=b.keyf_producttype,
keyf_project=b.keyf_project,
option3_flag=b.option3_flag,
xclass=b.xclass,
archive_flag=b.archive_flag,
pricing_ticket_firstsenddate=b.pricing_ticket_firstsenddate,
pricing_override_14day=b.pricing_override_14day,
final_approval_copy=b.final_approval_copy,
final_approval_photo=b.final_approval_photo,
final_approval_data=b.final_approval_data,
final_approval_merchant=b.final_approval_merchant,
final_approval_buyer=b.final_approval_buyer,
pricing_override_savings=b.pricing_override_savings,
option2_flag=b.option2_flag,
gmm=b.gmm,
pricing_override_onsaleratio=b.pricing_override_onsaleratio,
aol_featured=b.aol_featured,
aol_flag=b.aol_flag,
aol_isvalid=b.aol_isvalid,
inc_lastsenddate=b.inc_lastsenddate,
firstlivedate=b.firstlivedate,
SCENE7 = b.SCENE7,
AOL_ITEM_CATEGORIES = b.AOL_ITEM_CATEGORIES,
DVM_M = b.DVM_M,

action_publish_flag_wc=b.action_publish_flag_wc,
ACTION_VIEWABLE_WC=b.ACTION_VIEWABLE_WC,
item_number=b.item_number,
SUBCLASS = cast (b.SUBCLASS as int4),
CADENCE= b.CADENCE,
date_turn_off = b.date_turn_off,        
date_turn_on = b.date_turn_on,      
PRICING_TICKETESTABLISHED_DATE= b.PRICING_TICKETESTABLISHED_DATE,
FINAL_APPROVAL_FULL= b.FINAL_APPROVAL_FULL,
KEY_ITEM_FLAG= b.KEY_ITEM_FLAG,

last_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
from staging.staging_bdc_products b where
b.keyp_products = bdc_products.keyp_products ;

/* Insert new data */

INSERT INTO bdc_products(
keyp_products,  description,  page_type,
keyf_category_home, giftwrappable,  action_publish,
action_viewable, keyf_syndicate, sss_base_fee_exempt_flag,
sss_surcharge_fee, dvm_d,
dvm_v, division, keyf_images_primary,
option4_flag, keyf_producttype, keyf_project,
option3_flag, xclass, archive_flag,
pricing_ticket_firstsenddate, pricing_override_14day,
pricing_today_retail,
final_approval_copy, final_approval_photo,
final_approval_data, final_approval_merchant,
final_approval_buyer,
pricing_override_savings, option2_flag,
gmm, pricing_override_onsaleratio,
aol_featured,aol_flag,aol_isvalid,inc_lastsenddate,
firstlivedate, SCENE7, AOL_ITEM_CATEGORIES, DVM_M, action_publish_flag_wc,
ACTION_VIEWABLE_WC, item_number,
SUBCLASS, CADENCE,
date_turn_off, date_turn_on,
PRICING_TICKETESTABLISHED_DATE, FINAL_APPROVAL_FULL, KEY_ITEM_FLAG,
last_update
)
SELECT b.keyp_products,  b.description,  b.page_type,
b.keyf_category_home, b.giftwrappable,  b.action_publish,
b.action_viewable, b.keyf_syndicate, b.sss_base_fee_exempt_flag,
b.sss_surcharge_fee, b.dvm_d,
b.dvm_v, b.division, b.keyf_images_primary,
b.option4_flag, b.keyf_producttype, b.keyf_project,
b.option3_flag, b.xclass, b.archive_flag,
b.pricing_ticket_firstsenddate, b.pricing_override_14day,
b.pricing_today_retail,
b.final_approval_copy, b.final_approval_photo,
b.final_approval_data, b.final_approval_merchant,
b.final_approval_buyer,
b.pricing_override_savings, b.option2_flag,
b.gmm, b.pricing_override_onsaleratio,
b.aol_featured,b.aol_flag,b.aol_isvalid,b.inc_lastsenddate,
b.firstlivedate, b.SCENE7, b.AOL_ITEM_CATEGORIES,     b.DVM_M,b.action_publish_flag_wc,
b.ACTION_VIEWABLE_WC, b.item_number,
cast (b.SUBCLASS as int4), b.CADENCE,
b.date_turn_off, b.date_turn_on,
b.PRICING_TICKETESTABLISHED_DATE, b.FINAL_APPROVAL_FULL, b.KEY_ITEM_FLAG
,current_timestamp
FROM staging.staging_bdc_products b
LEFT OUTER JOIN bdc_products p on b.keyp_products = p.keyp_products
WHERE  p.keyp_products is null;


SELECT  create_bdcprodidx();

UPDATE bdc_products
set pricing_daysonsale_currentfy = totaldays
FROM  product_onsalesdays
WHERE keyf_products = keyp_products
;`
```

Could you please help on how to fix this issue? DO we need to split the sql?

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#prepare

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all.  See the excerpt below from the `DBD::Pg` module [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#prepare):

> You cannot send more than one command at a time in the same prepare command (by separating them with semi-colons) when using server-side prepares.